# Establishing the validity of an argument.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I've been trying to determine the validity of a particular argument for some time now and I've had no luck in figuring it out. The argument in question goes as follows:
\begin{align}
& p \wedge q \\
& p \rightarrow(r\wedge q) \\
& r \rightarrow(s \vee t) \\
& \sim s \\
\hline  & \therefore t
\end{align}

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the rules of inference but I don't see how this is a valid argument.
**Edit
I've started to use a step-by-step approach to determining the validity and have come up with the following:
\begin{align}
1. & & & p\rightarrow (r\wedge 1) \\
2. & & & p \wedge q \\
3. & & & (r\wedge q)\wedge q \\
4. & & & r \rightarrow (s \vee t)
\end{align}

And thats as far as I've gotten... Where should I go from here?

Comment: One way of doing this is by truth tables.  An argument is valid precisely if the conclusion is true in every row of the truth table in which the premises are true.  This truth table will have 32 rows since there are four variables, $p,q,r,s,t$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I would not call this an argument, though. The conclusion follows from the premises, but an argument would show how and why it follows. Use of truth tables is valid, but depends on a theorem which says that truths established by truth tables are the same as those which can be established using the rules of deduction (for standard logic).

Comment: I should have said an _inference_, rather than an _argument_.

Comment: What are your inference rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is valid. You can see it informally as follows. If $t$ were false, then both $s$ and $t$ would be false. Since $r\to(s\lor t)$, this means that $r$ must be false, and since $p\to(r\land q)$, this in turn means that $p$ must be false. But then $p\land q$ is false, contrary to the first assumption.

If all else fails, you can work it out by a truth table, verifying that in every line in which all four of the hypotheses are true, $t$ is true. We don’t even have to look at all $32$ possible lines: from the hypothesis $p\land q$ we know that $p$ and $q$ are true, and from the hypothesis $\neg s$ we know that $s$ is false. Thus, only $r$ and $t$ are free to vary, and we have only four lines to consider:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
p&q&s&r&t&r\land q&p\to(r\land q)&s\lor t&r\to(s\lor t)\\ \hline
T&T&F&T&\color{brown}T&T&\color{brown}T&T&\color{brown}T\\
T&T&F&T&F&T&T&F&F\\
T&T&F&F&T&F&F&T&T\\
T&T&F&F&F&F&F&F&T
\end{array}$$

The only row in which the second and third hypotheses are both true is the first, and in it $t$ is also true.

Answer (score 0):

In words:

By the first statement, $p$ and $q$ are both true.

By the second statement, the fact that $p$ is true forces both $r$ and $q$ to be true.

By the third statement, the fact that $r$ is true forces $s \vee t$ to be true. Since $s$ is false (by the fourth statement), $t$ must be true.